# Creating a new script causes Visual Studio to unload project

Tags: unity-game-engine

#### Issue

When I create a new script from the Unity Editor and enter it, while Visual Studio is already started, the Project in visual studio is unloaded. Clicking "Reload Project" does nothing. The only solution I have is to restart Unity every time you create a new script. Surprisingly google isn't helping much either which leads me to believe this isn't the case for everyone using Windows & Visual Studio.

Anything anyone of you have encountered?

#### Versions

Visual Studio Professional 2013, 12.0.30110.00 Update1

Unity 5.4.1f1 (64bit)

Comment: Well, you failed to mentiond both Unity and VS version. I suggest you uninstall both of them, restart computer and install them again. Make sure to install Unity 5.5(latest). Maybe a problem like this has now been fixed.

Comment: Fair enough, yeah. Kinda just wanted to know if this was the default behaviour but somehow went undocumented. Edited post with specified details but I'm guessing your suggestion might be the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. Uninstall all of them including Visual Studio Tools for Unity then install them again. Sometimes, Uninstall and Install is all you have to do. Just make sure to restart after Uninstalling them.